# CA::AttrList::set(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) Crash

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Recently I'm getting a lot of crashes on Crashlytics with title :

```
QuartzCore
CA::AttrList::set(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*)
```

This crash is caused i think by Google Admob SDK, And only on iOS 8.4.1. i did a little research to find out whats causing that and to find a solution for it, I've found a report in Admob Docs : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/Qnfr17UHJ6Q , which have similar crash report.

They said that i have to turn off `UIView` Animation For `GADBannerView` : `[GADBannerView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];` , But thats not a solution at all because Google Banner View doesn't subclass UIViewAnimation thus its gonna turn off all the animation inside the app including push, tableview animation ..etc

I don't know if somebody did face this crash before and what was the cause of that, And note that I'm not using `WebView` At all in my application.

And crash thread details is here:

```
#0
Crashed: WebThread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000007fe10153
 Raw
0   libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 21
1   QuartzCore  
CA::AttrList::set(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 412
2
QuartzCore  
CAAnimation_setter(CAAnimation*, unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 162
3   QuartzCore  
-[CAAnimation setDelegate:] + 18
4   UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState setAnimationAttributes:correctZeroDuration:skipDelegateAssignment:customCurve:] + 742
5   UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState animationForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 648
6   UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 40
7   UIKit   
+[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 88
8   UIKit   
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 116
9   QuartzCore  
-[CALayer actionForKey:] + 146
10  QuartzCore  
actionForKey(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, NSString*) + 56
11  QuartzCore  
CA::Layer::begin_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*&) + 130
12  QuartzCore  
CA::Layer::set_position(CA::Vec2<double> const&, bool) + 348
13  QuartzCore  
-[CALayer setPosition:] + 54
14  QuartzCore  
-[CALayer setFrame:] + 574
15  UIKit   
-[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 264
16  UIKit   
-[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] + 170
17  UIKit   
-[UIImageView setFrame:] + 38
18  UIKit   
-[UISlider _layoutSubviewsForBoundsChange:] + 1082
19  UIKit   
-[UISlider _sliderAnimationDidStop:finished:context:] + 74
20  UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
21  UIKit   
+[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 320
22  UIKit   
-[UISlider setValue:animated:] + 796
23  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeSlider volumeController:volumeValueDidChange:] + 78
24  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeController updateVolumeValue] + 252
25  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeSlider didMoveToSuperview] + 126
26  UIKit   
-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 428
27  UIKit   
-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1498
28  UIKit   
-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
29  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeView _createSubviews] + 236
30  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeView _initWithStyle:] + 212
31  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:style:] + 80
32  MediaPlayer 
-[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:] + 38
33  UIKit   
-[UIView init] + 44
34  WebCore 
-[WebMediaSessionHelper allocateVolumeView] + 264
35  WebCore 
-[WebMediaSessionHelper initWithCallback:] + 394
36  WebCore 
WebCore::MediaSessionManageriOS::MediaSessionManageriOS() + 172
37  WebCore 
WebCore::MediaSessionManager::sharedManager() + 124
38  WebCore 
WebCore::MediaSession::MediaSession(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 32
39  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLMediaSession::create(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 20
40  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::HTMLMediaElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 1046
41  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLAudioElement::create(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 36
42  WebCore 
WebCore::audioConstructor(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 56
43  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLElementFactory::createElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 232
44  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLDocument::createElement(WTF::AtomicString const&, int&) + 88
45  WebCore 
WebCore::jsDocumentPrototypeFunctionCreateElement(JSC::ExecState*) + 242
46  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 21314
47  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 20278
48  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 20278
49  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 20278
50  JavaScriptCore  
callToJavaScript + 334
51  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 36
52  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 350
53  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 62
54  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::boundFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 342
55  JavaScriptCore  
callToNativeFunction + 318
56  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 418
57  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, JSC::JSValue*) + 64
58  WebCore 
WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 520
59  WebCore 
WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 650
60  WebCore 
WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 162
61  WebCore 
WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event&) const + 60
62  WebCore 
WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 692
63  WebCore 
WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 20
64  WebCore 
WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 92
65  WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::prepareToStopParsing() + 118
66  WebCore 
non-virtual thunk to WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::notifyFinished(WebCore::CachedResource*) + 72
67  WebCore 
WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 58
68  WebCore 
WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 128
69  CFNetwork   
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 78
70  CFNetwork   
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 60
71  CFNetwork   
RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 60
72  CoreFoundation  
CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
73  CFNetwork   
RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
74  CFNetwork   
MultiplexerSource::perform() + 216
75  CFNetwork   
MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
76  CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
77  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
78  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun + 772
79  CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
80  CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
81  WebCore 
RunWebThread(void*) + 418
82  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_body + 138
83  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_start + 118
84
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
thread_start + 8
```

And Here is some of my code for Banner View :

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    log.PrintMe("bannerViewDidLoadAd")

    admobBannerView.hidden = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        adBannerView.alpha = 1 //iAd Banner
    }

}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    log.PrintMe("bannerViewActionDidFinish")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    log.PrintMe("didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error)")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in

        adBannerView.alpha = 0 //iAd Banner
    }

    admobBannerView.hidden = false
}


func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```